# How do I set the delegate of a UITableViewCell from a UITableViewDataSource?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, delegates, datasource

In my UITableViewController I have set an external class for the DataSource. As below

```
class HomeViewDataSource: NSObject, UITableViewDataSource {

  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
      let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(myCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath)
      cell.delegate = //Should I set this to the view controller?
      return cell
  }
}
```

As you can see, I have a reusable cell that I would like to set a delegate for. In the cell I have a button that triggers an event on the UITableViewController. For now, I have set the delegate of the cell to my UITableViewController so that it can perform a network call. I do not believe I am doing this in a correct MVC format however.

The network call in the UITableViewController uses a property from an array in the UITableViewDataSource.

What is a better method to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I had another think about this and decided to try using a closure.
Here is how I could do it.

```
//MyCellClass: UITableViewCell

@IBAction func buttonPressed(sender:UIButton) {
  buttonNetworkCall?(self)
}
```

and in the UITableViewDataSource

```
//HomeViewDataSource: NSObject, UITableViewDataSource {

  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(myCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath)

    cell.buttonNetworkCall = { (cell) in
      self.makeButtonNetworkCall(cell)
    }

  return cell
  }
}
```